# Metro App Permissions Settings Charm

Tags: windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

My **Metro App**, uses `Notifications` and requires `Lock Screen Access`. All working great! Now, I notice that a `Permissions` settings charm is automatically created, with an option to turn **On** and **Off** these settings. So this leads me to the following questions:

1. Do these settings automatically prevent `Notifications` from being
   shown if set to **On** or **Off**?
2. Or does it write a value somewhere that I need to read, and then
   determine in my app if I need to `Show Notifications` or not?

If the answer to question 1 is **Yes**, great! I don't need to do anything. However, if **No** please advise on where these settings can be read from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user sets the `Notifications` permission to **Off** then **no notification will shown.**

So when the setting is **Off** then the `toastNotifier.Show(toast)` call will do nothing so you don't need to do anything extra.

However if you want to specially handle the case when the notification are turned off then you can check this permission setting with the [ToastNotifier.Setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotifier.setting.aspx)

```
ToastNotifier toastNotifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
if (toastNotifier.Setting == NotificationSetting.Enabled) 
   toastNotifier.Show(toast);
else
   //Notifacation are disabled do something else
```